# How do I calculate the *signed* area of a triangle in 3D space?

Tags: geometry, triangles

The signed area of a triangle is often given simply as

\begin{equation}
  A\left( \Delta \right) = \frac{1}{2}\left|\begin{matrix}
    x_{0} & y_{0} & 1  \\
    x_{1} & y_{1} & 1  \\
    x_{2} & y_{2} & 1
\end{matrix}\right|
\end{equation}

for $V_i = \left(x_i,y_i\right)$.

This, of course, only works for vertices located on a 2D plane.

What is the analog for the **signed** area of a triangle in 3D space, having $x,y,z$ coordinates?

Comment: You cannot have signed area of a 2D shape embedded in 3D. The closest analogue would be the *vector area*, $\mathbf S=\frac12(\mathbf v_1-\mathbf v_0)\times(\mathbf v_2-\mathbf v_0)$, which is a vector whose magnitude is the area and whose direction is the normal of the plane containing the triangle.

Comment: Thank you. Why can't one have a signed area in 3D?

Comment: Consider an equilateral triangle in the $xy$ plane. If you swap two of its vertices, the hypothetical "signed area" should change sign. But you can achieve the same effect by rotating the triangle in a continuous motion (with the perpendicular bisector of the two swapped vertices as the axis of rotation). At what point in the process would the sign of the "signed area" flip?

Comment: Consider a triangulated non orientable Moebius band. How would you define the sum of the signed areas of the triangles if there is no compatible orientations of all of the triangles?

Answer (score 0):

In 2D the sign of the determinant defining the area of the triangle
is determined by the order in which you consider the vertices, i.e.
the three rows in your determinant
$$
\left| {\matrix{
   {x_0 } & {y_0 } & 1  \cr 
   {x_1 } & {y_1 } & 1  \cr 
   {x_2 } & {y_2 } & 1  \cr 
 } } \right|
$$
or otherwise the two vertical vectors corresponding to sides
departing from $(x_0,y_0)$ which appear in the related determinant
$$
\left| {\matrix{
   {x_1  - x_0 } & {x_2  - x_0 }  \cr 
   {y_1  - y_0 } & {y_2  - y_0 }  \cr 
 } } \right|
$$

If you swap two of them you change the sign.

The sign defines the [chirality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(mathematics))
according for instance to the *right-hand rule* well known in physics.

Now if you  translate or rotate the triangle as a "rigid body", by multiplying by a rotation matrix with
determinant $+1$, the chirality is not changed.

So, given a triangle in 3D, once you establish the order of vetices/the sides, it will have a precise signed area, which is the same
that you have once you rotate it onto the $x-y$ plane.