# Is there a notation for the "magnitude with sign" of the cross product?

Tags: soft-question, notation

If $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^3$, then
$$a\times b = \hat{n}\|a\|\|b\|\sin\alpha$$
where $\hat{n}$ is perpendicular to $a,b$ and $\alpha$ is the angle between $a$ and $b$. Does there exist a standard notation for the "signed norm"
$$\|a\|\|b\|\sin\alpha$$?

Comment: There is no way to consistently define the sign of the magnitude of a cross product. See my comments here: [How do I calculate the *signed* area of a triangle in 3D space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2511452/856)

Comment: @Rahul It seems the OP asks for the "sined norm" rather than "signed norm"